# How do I make one local git repo available on two different heroku projects?

Tags: git, heroku

I've already `heroku create`'d a project under my local repo. This one was with the default and newer heroku-16 stack.

I then created a stack using the older cedar-16 stack.

I'm wondering now, how do I make the same git repo available on my second cedar-16 stack?

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying with git, you can add the other application that you've created as a second remote:

`git remote add my-remote-name https://git.heroku.com/my-application-slug.git`

Then you can push your repository to the new remote: `git push my-remote-name master`.